# Copy files in nested folders in S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to copy a file in one folder in source bucket to another folder in the same bucket under source folder using boto3.

Source bucket: Testing

Source Path: A/B/C/D/E/F..

I have some files in C, which I need to move to E.

My problem is, lambda is running in loop for this. I have this lambda which get triggered when my file comes to C, and then ut trigger another one to do something else. Now between these two, I have to move the file from C to E and then trigger the lambda to perform next operation.

Anyone have any insight how I can fix that issue of lambda running in loop?

Comment: Please edit with your program so that we can effectively visualize your issue.

Comment: you want my code? I mean my copying part is working but issue is moment its copying under folder E, as this folder is inside C ( which is kind of parent here) it acts as a trigger and this way lambda is in loop.

Comment: so my file comes in `BUCKETNAME/20181012/` and then moment file comes it trigger a lambda, which basically going to trigger something else but before that trigger happens, I need to move the file from `BUCKETNAME/20181012/` to `BUCKETNAME/20181012/ABC/` here and as ABC is under `BUCKETNAME/20181012/` it still acts as nested folder and lambda again got triggered.

Comment: It would be best to add your code so users can help you.

Comment: You can't just tell me what happened, I can't help you that way.

Comment: there is no folders in aws, only files/data, slash is just part of file name

Comment: you might need add checks of trailing /abc/ before ''file' name in your lambda

Comment: What do you mean by "that issue of lambda running in loop"? Do you mean that copying the file causes another Lambda function to be triggered and you do not wish this to happen?  If so, you can configure the event to only trigger on a certain path prefix. If, however, you are copying to a sub-directory of the original path, this won't work. So, either move it somewhere else, or have your Lambda code check the path and exit if no further processing is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In S3 there is no folder. You'd better see it as a bucket-key-value. *The folder-like representation you see in the console is just a visualisation.*

Your Lambda is triggered by an event of file modification in your bucket. You have to play with the **prefix** and the **suffix** of the S3 event.

Do you control the name of the file you put in S3?

- Yes. Suppose your filename always starts with `new`. Set your event with **prefix: `A/B/C/new`**. When a file get in `A/B/C/new...` the lambda is triggered because it matches the prefix, when the same files goes to `A/B/C/D/E/new...` no lambda is triggered because the prefix doesn't match.
- No. Then change your folder hierarchy. Set your event with **prefix: `A/B/C/`**. Move the file to any key (i.e. "folder") that doesn't start with `A/B/C`, for example `A/B/E`. Thus, the second key will not match the prefix.

The suffix is not of any help unless you may rename the suffix of the file. If you are able to rename the file you create an event with **suffix: `.abc`**, and when moving the file you rename it to something ending in `.xyz`. Thus only the `.abc` files will trigger the Lambda, wherever they are situated.